# div not resizing with certain content

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a mock layout of a shopping and I can't seem to get the layout to resize correctly when additional items are added, the divs just overlap. But when content is just text and images, it works fine. Any one have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

This is the test layout that works fine.
[Layout Working](http://www.jsbaits.com/jssite/shop/test.php)

This is the cart layout that overlaps.
[Layout Not Working](http://www.jsbaits.com/jssite/shop/view_cart.php)

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 background:transparent;
}
body:after {
    content:"";
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    display:block;
    background:url(../background.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
 z-index: -2;
}
#side-bar {
 position:fixed;
 float:left;
 width:25%;
 min-width:200px;
 height:100%;
 min-height:420px;
 z-index: 3;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 box-shadow: 3px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#content {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 75%;
 z-index: 2;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#nav-bar {
 width:100%;
 min-width:350px;
 height:50px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 color: white;
}
#nav-bar ul {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-width:280px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
#nav-bar li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 width: 13%;
 min-width:60px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
#nav-bar a:link, a:visited {
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav-bar a:hover {
    color: #FAED26;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#advert {
 top:50px;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 color: #FAED26;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
#advert h1 {
 line-height: 40px;
}
#advert h2 {
 margin-top:-12px;
 font-size: 11px;
}
#sub-nav {
 top:100px;
 width:100%;
 min-width:350px;
 height:25px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size:12px;
 color: white;
}
#sub-nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
 display: table;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
} 
#sub-nav li {
 list-style: none;
 display:table-cell;
 width:16.6%;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
#sub-nav li:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
#sub-nav a:link, a:visited {
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
#sub-nav a:hover {
    color: #FAED26;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#page-nav-top {
 top:125px;
 width:100%;
 min-width:350px;
 height:25px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size:10px;
 color: white;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}
#page-nav-top .left {
 position:relative;
 float: left;
 left: 50px;
 height:25px;
 line-height:25px;
}
#page-nav-top .right {
 position:relative;
 float: right;
 right: 50px;
 height:25px;
 line-height:25px;
}
#page-break-1 {
 top:150px;
 width:100%;
 height:5px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#page-break-2 {
 width:100%;
 height:5px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#page-content {
 top:165px;
    bottom:200px;
    width:100%;
 height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 min-height: calc(100vh - 490px);
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
 height:330px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

```html
<div id="side-bar"></div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="nav-bar">
   <?php include ("nav-bar.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <div id="advert">
   <?php include ("advert.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <div id="sub-nav">
   <?php include ("sub-nav/cart.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <div id="page-nav-top">
   <div class="left">HOME >>
    <font style="color: #FAED26;">SHOPPING CART</font>
   </div>
   <div class="right"><a href="javascript:history.back()">GO BACK</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-break-1"></div>
  <div id="page-content"><br>
text<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
text<br>
</div>
  <div id="page-break-2"></div>
  <div id="footer">
   <?php include ("footer.php"); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have floating element, it means that they are taken out of the normal flow.
You could apply a clearfix to the parent of your floating elements in order to make it take the height of its children.

In your exemple you could add:

```
#page-content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: A better solution, though not as well supported, is to use `display: flow-root` on `#page-content`. It's currently supported by Chrome, FF, and Opera, though not Safari or IE/Edge.

Comment: @jhpratt I must admit that I didn't even know about it ! As you said, the support is not perfect, but I'll keep it in mind ! https://www.caniuse.com/#search=flow-root

Comment: Yeah, it was released in March in both Chrome and FF (Opera uses Chrome's rendering engine). I currently use `@supports` for feature detection, but that's just an advantage of using a preprocessor (I can forget about it entirely)..

Comment: Thank you for that, I tried using clearfix but obviously wasn't executing it properly!